# How to deal with message fragmentation in Perl TCP socket?

Tags: c++, perl, sockets, tcp, communication

I have a socket comminucation between Perl client and C++ server.

Perl code:

```
  if (!socket(SERVER, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp'))) {
    die "Can't allocate socket\n";
  } elsif (!connect(SERVER,sockaddr_in($PORT, $tcp_addr))) {
    die "Can't connect to server at $tcp_addr port $PORT...\n";
  }

  SERVER -> autoflush(1);

  print SERVER "$line";
```

If `$line` was too long, it is being fragmented, and on the C++ server side I have to call `recv` several times (without even knowing the actual expected length!).

What are the best ways to deal with it?

I thought of some ways:

1. Maybe there is some Perl module that deals with it?
2. Maybe I can just turn off fragmentation, but wouldn't it cause more transmission fails?
3. I can just add the message length to the sent message, and I will call `recv` until I receive the whole message, but isn't it just ugly?
4. Anything else?

What would the best solution be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the message length as a 4byte header to the message. This is not ugly, but just as the "pros" do it. TCP/IP is a stream oriented protocol. You were just lucky that you got your messages in one recv call. It is possible to get any number of bytes, only half a message, one and a half message etc. as tcp/ip is transferring a continuous stream of bytes without any notion of packets at that level.

The good side of this is that you can buffer your messages in userspace and can read as many bytes as you want into that buffer, and the process multiple messages out of this buffer isntead of repeatedly calling recv()

Comment: Surely it is the case that, as far as the protocol stack is concerned, it will be IP that is fragmenting the message (if necessary) but also the message will be re-assembled by IP at the destination. Is it not true then that if the application level tx and rx buffers are large enough it should appear as a single message, thus the OPs problem is at an application level, rather than the stack breaking messages up? If this isn't true, then  applications would have to do re-assembly of messages based on the MTU of the media they are being sent over.

Comment: @blankabout: You seem to be confusing IP fragmentation for a single TCP packet with the fact that when your send() out some bytes via tcp, then the OS is free to put it in as many TCP messagees it thinks is useful. Thus depending on how it has divided the data up, and the timing of the recv() calls, the buffer will be filled with only a partial message, exactly a whole message, or more than one message. Unless the sender uses cork, when it send()s multiple messages fast enough, you will almost never have the case of recv()ing exactly one message.

Comment: What I do not understand is why a message would be broken up if application level buffers are of an adequate size. As far as I can see, if an application on host A sends a single message to an application on host B then the message should be received at the application level as a single message. If the application has allowed a large enough tx buffer why is the OS fragmenting it prior to sending it down the stack?

Comment: @blankabout: because the OS works with complex algorithms that is using timeouts, and the receiver does not know anything about the size of the message, and how many data there possibly would be. Imagine the other way round, what would happen if the program tries to receive 5000 bytes, but somehow the sender only sent 4096? after a timeout the OS simply returns and tells the program that it received 4096 bytes. The same would happen if the remaining bytes only arrive after the timeout (e.g. because of a slow/disturbed line)

Answer (score 5):

The best solution is to keep calling 'recv' until you have the whole message. If necessary to determine when you have the whole message, either prefix the message with its length or put a terminator after it. I'm not sure why you think that's ugly.